# Reboot disable and enable usb ports

Tags: usb, 15.10

Ubuntu Server 15.10

Having issues with 2 usb receivers with same serial number. My service mixes them up. But if I remove the usb plugs on reboot and then attach them in specific order it works fine.

Can I on boot disable all usb ports (port 1 - 8). Then on a delay enable only port 2 and later 4.

Comment: As an alternative, can't you use a single usb receiver instead of two?

Comment: No. It's satellite receivers so one for each on the wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I cannot guarantee this will work, but give it a try.**

First, show all USB devices:

```
sudo lsusb -t
```

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/14p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
```

You can then disable the wanted USB port on the root hub.

Disabling a port on the root hub means I can disable my webcam (uvcvideo) like this (bus 3, port 8):

```
echo '3-8' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

I can also re-enable it:

```
 echo '3-8' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
```

Do this with **caution**, as inputting wrong numbers can disable your keyboard. Ideally, make sure you can still type if USB is turned off (for example, on a laptop you have a built-in keyboard)

As you are saying you are using a server, you could setup SSH to the machine to be able to type if the keyboard gets disactivated while trying this.

A reboot can probably solve a disabled keyboard as well.

As for disabling it on the fly just after booting, put these commands in a script (adapt to your own situation):

```
sleep 20 #try if this is needed, needs an increase etc
echo '3-8' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind # detach device 1
echo '2-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind # detach device 2
sleep 5
echo '3-8' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind # attach device 1
sleep 5
echo '2-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind # attach device 2
```